# How to get given App names and details by searching app name in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, itunes, itunes-sdk

I need to connect my app from xcode to iTunes to fetching apps details. I will provide a name and then it will return me a result of those apps names which contains the keywords. Then I need to fetch the details from those names, like showing the price, screenshoots, descr

Like, suppose, I want to search by bluetooth from my app which will be build by me, and I will get those apps names by the keyword and the details of those apps as well from objective c??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need to tap into the iTunes Search API:

http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But Does it fetch app names from iTunes or it only fetches song or music albums and artist details??

Comment: I'd recommend you actually read the link I posted - there's clearly an example on how to search the appstore in there! You can search all stores or specify what and where you want to search.

Comment: Awesome! Remember to use the tick to accept answers if you can :)